# How can you see the difference between two files in Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, diff

I've seen some SVN tools that use a "diff" command that will highlight the differences between two files. However, I don't understand how to do this within Visual Web developer 2010 (Express). Any help discovering this method will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

PS: I include visual-studio-2010 in the tags as I think it is the closest thing to web developer 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if VWD has its own file compare function, but you could use WinDiff from the Windows SDK.  Here is the link for version 7.1 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: I just downloaded this, and will use it. I'd really like to be able to do it within VWD, but this is a good resource!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385990.aspx

> To compare two files
>
> ```
> On the View menu, click Other Windows, and then click Source Control Explorer.
>
> In Source Control Explorer, right-click the version of the file that you want to 
>   compare, and then click Compare.
> NoteNote
>
> As an option, you can right-click a file in Solution Explorer and then click Compare.
>
> The Compare dialog box appears and the local path of the file that you selected is 
>   in the Source Path box.
>
> Enter the Target Path or click Browse and locate the target folder.
>
> Under Target Version, select the Type you want to use for comparison: Changeset,
>    Date, Label, Latest Version, or Workspace Version.
>
> Click OK.
>
> If the files have no differences, the Microsoft Visual Studio dialog box appears,
>   informing you that the files are identical. Click OK.
>
> Otherwise, a difference window displays the files side by side.
> ```

Comment: It's just that I don't see the Source Control Explorer under the Other Windows menu

Comment: @Silver, this is for VS2010 (as per your tag in question), not sure if will work in VWD.

Answer (score 0):

I use devart's code compare tool and it worked really good for me. You can download it from here.

http://www.devart.com/codecompare/